# runMI function error: 'no slot of name "internalList" for this object of class "lavaanList"'

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I have run a multiple imputation (m=45, 10 iterations) using MICE and am attempting to fit a series of confirmatory factor analysis and structural equation models on the imputed datasets using the runMI function from semTools. Nearly all of my variables are Likert scales, coded as ordered/ordinal. Here is my code for the first CFA, where mi.res.train is the mice-generated mids object:

```
ipc_c_model <- '
IPC_C =~ t2IPC6_1 + t2IPC6_2 + t2IPC6_3 + t2IPC6_4 + t2IPC6_5 + t2IPC6_6 + t2IPC6_7'
ipc_c_fit <- runMI(ipc_c_model, mi.res.train, fun = "cfa", ordered = TRUE)
```

The model does not fit and returns the following error:

> Error in slot(value, what) :
> no slot of name "internalList" for this object of class "lavaanList"

As far as I can see, the lavaan.mi object that this is supposed to create is a special type of lavaanList object. Any ideas as to what may be causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Code fragments with no data are seldom sufficient in the degugging task. If you have already googled for this error message then It seems unlikely that we will be able to give a convincing answer on this basis. ( The formula spec looks weird but lavaan formulas often look weird to me.)

Comment: `semTools` does not use the `@internalList` slot in `lavaan.mi` objects.  A full script (minimally sufficient to produce the error) could reveal something, as could your `sessionInfo()` output.

Comment: Hi all: thanks for this feedback--unfortunately am using a restricted-use dataset so could not share much data without some extra steps. Fortunately, I updated a few packages and the code now appears to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all: thanks for this feedback--unfortunately am using a restricted-use dataset so could not share much data without some extra steps. Fortunately, I updated a few packages and the code now appears to be working. I'd tried that previously but apparently missed the lavaan package itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).